# unable to link object file so i can't make it executalbe

Tags: bash, assembly, ld

I've started learning assembly language (from tutorials point)
and they said:

> To link the object file and create an executable file named hello,
> type ld -m elf_i386 -s -o hello hello.o

But the -m is not found in my terminal

Here's the tutorial link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm

I'm using persistence parrot os 4.6 VERSION NASM (LATEST ONE).

Answer (score 2):

"Type" is an instruction to you to use your keyboard to input this to a shell.

```
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o hello hello.o
```

It seems you did:

```
$ type ld -m ...
ld is /usr/bin/ld
bash: type: -m: not found
```

`type` is a shell built-in that can take multiple arguments and tell you whether each of them is an alias, shell-function, or found in the `$PATH`.

The tutorial you were using did *not* mean to use the `type` command, it wanted you to run `ld`, the linker.  That's why it bolded the `ld` command, not including the word `type`.

"Type" is a poor choice of words.  I would have said "run", and assumed that readers would copy/paste the text into a terminal window.  But in any case, **they're just using "type" as a plain English word, not part of the command.**